# Starter-Isolated-Storage Pack on Windows Phone 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am making a small Windows Phone 7 application and have lots of text files used by the app. They all contains LOTS of lines. Is it possible to make some files be already installed when I launch the application? I know that emulator doesn't save isolated storage when closed but I don't need it. I want to make some data files which would be already in the storage when my app starts for the first time. If it is possible, how do I do that?

I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for development/debugging purposes, then you might find the [Windows Phone 7 Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) useful. If you mean at runtime, then no, you can't pre-deploy files to isolated storage as part of the installation, they would have to be part of the XAP or downloaded from a web service. If they're part of the XAP, then it really doesn't seem worth putting them into isolated storage, though :P

Comment: Unless you need to modify the files at runtime, can't do that if they're part of the XAP :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Mango" SDK ships with the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) that can take and restore snapshots of an application's isolated storage to/from a local directory:

```
# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe ts xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"

# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe rs xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"
```